# Bigquery Command Line Query with ">" not working

Tags: google-bigquery

Initially took me a while to figure out that ">" causes an issue in cmd and learned from one of the answers that escaping with ^ works. So after changing my query to below format it works fine.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=  (SELECT * FROM `dataset_ID.table_nm` GROUP BY AAA HAVING SUM(BBB)^>0 )
```

But now I am trying to run the same query through a file.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table=  --flagfile="Y:query.sql"
```

However above it gives me an error if I have "^>".
Error in query string: Error processing job Syntax error: Unexpected ">" at [1:227]

If I don't have "^" in front of the ">" the query doesn't return an error but the result is empty..

Hoping someone could help out with the issue above.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that there are any rows where `BBB` is greater than zero?

Comment: I've checked the query in Web UI. Also when i'm not calling the sql file and submitting the query directly in the cmd it returns results. To add a little this is part of a big query that we run on a regular basis through the web ui. But we are trying to automate the process with the parameter, etc. Hence the SQL file.

Comment: You can use `bq show -j <job_id>` to see the contents of the query that actually ran.